How did the people of the bible view individuals with titles "saviour" and "Lord of lords."?
Deuteronomy 10:17 YLT

for Jehovah your God -- He is God of the gods, and Lord of the lords; God, the great, the mighty, and the fearful; who accepteth not persons, nor taketh a bribe;

Revelation 17:14 YLT

these with the Lamb shall make war, and the Lamb shall overcome them, because Lord of lords he is, and King of kings, and those with him are called, and choice, and stedfast.'

If John called Jesus Lord of lords, did his contemporaries believed that Jesus is YHWH because in Deuteronomy 10:17 we find the YHWH is the God of gods and Lord of lords? Is "Lord of lords" the same as "God of gods"? If YHWH is the only saviour as Isaiah 43:11 shows, what was the understanding of the people of the bible about Othniel (Judges 3:9) and Ehud (Judges 3:15) Jesus (Matthew 1:21) as saviours? Did the followers of Jesus not notice any difference between YHWH and Jesus?
Did the Jewish followers of Jesus call the Christ, a fellow Jew, Lord YHWH.? Should we supposed that the followers of Jesus did not see any difference between YHWH and Jesus?

Savior
Let us immediately distinguish between:

the unique function of Saviour from sin as was YHWH (Isa 43:3, 11, 14, 44:24, 45:17, 21, 49:7 ) or Jesus (Acts 4:11, 12; vs;
a miliary deliverer as were Othniel (Judges 3:9) and Ehud (Judges 3:15)

Now, it is well recognized that the judges and kings were only vice-regents of YHWH Himself 1 Sam 8:7, 8, 24:6, 2 Sam 19:21, 1 Chron 28:5, 29:23, 2 Chron 9:8, 13:8, Ps 5:2, 44:4.  Thus, the real and only king of Israel was God Himself.  Jesus also took this title of King of Israel Matt 1:1, 20, 9:27, 12:23, 15:22, 20:30, 15, 21:9, 15, Mark 10:35, Luke 1:32, 33, 18:38, 39, John 1:49, Acts 13:32-37, Heb 1:8.
Note especially, what the angel said to Mary before Jesus’ birth in Luke 1:32, 33 –

He will be great and will be called the Son of the Most High. The Lord
God will give Him the throne of His father David, and He will reign
over the house of Jacob forever. His kingdom will never end!

Lord of Lords
This title occurs in Deut 10:17, Ps 136:3, 26 and is applied only to YHWH/God in the OT.  In the NT is applied to Jesus in Rev 17:14, 19:16.  Thus, the ancient Israelites never used this title for anyone except YHWH.
Lord of All
This title occurs in Deut 10:17, Josh 3:11, 13, Ps 97:5, Zech 4:14, 6:5, Mic 4:13 and is only applied to YHWH.  In the NT it is applied to Jesus in Acts 10:36, Rom 10:12 (Col 1:15).
The same is true of other exclusive titles of YHWH in the OT vs Jesus in the NT such as:

"Creator" Isa 44:24, 45:18 (Ps 33:6, 9) vs Jesus John 1:3, 10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2, 10
"Light..." Ps 27:1, Micah 7:8, Isa 9:2, vs Jesus John 1:4, 5, 9, 8:12, 9:5, 1 John 1:5-7, Matt 4:15, 16
"One who Searches hearts and minds", Jer 11:20, 17:10, 1 Sam 16:7; vs Jesus Rev 2:23
"Rescuer from Egypt", Ex 20:2, Lev 25:38, 26:13, Deut 5:6, 15, 6:12, 13:5, 10, 20:1, Josh 2:1. 6:8, Amos 2:6, 10; vs Jesus Jude 5
etc, there are many more.

Further, the NT writers even take passages about YHWH on the OT and apply them directly to Jesus in the NT such as

Deut 32:43 (LXX) vs Heb 1:6
Ps 31:5 vs Acts 7:59
Ps 34:8 vs 1 Peter 2:3
Ps 45:6, 7, vs Heb 1:8, 9
Ps 68:18 vs Eph 4:8
Ps 102:25-27 vs Heb 1:10-12
Isa 8:13 vs 2 Peter 3;15
Isa 40:3 vs Matt 3;3, Mark 1:3, Luke 3:4, Luke 1:23
Isa 45:23 vs Phil 2:10, 11
etc - there are many more.

Thus, the NT writers were at some pains to show that Jesus was YHWH of the OT.

With these titles applied to Jesus, Did his contemporaries view him as YHWH, God of God's?. Did the followers of Jesus not noticed any difference between YHWH and Jesus?

@AlexBalilo - I think that is the point - they recognized Jesus as YHWH as evidenced by Jesus' title of "God" as per Matt 1:22, 23; John 1:1, 18, 20:28; Col 2:9, Rom 9:5, Heb 1:8, 9; Tit 2:13, 2 Peter 1:1, 1 Tim 3:16; Phil 2:5-8. Indeed, Jesus also called himself "I Am", Mark 6:50, Mark 13:6, 14:27, 62; Luke 21:8, 22:70, John 4:26, 6:20, 8:24, 28, 58, 13:9, 18:5-8.   Lastly, "God of gods" is only ever applied to YHWH and never used in the NT.

@Dottard.I think there were some in the people during his time that were analytical and not unsophisticated .How can they not see the difference between YHWH and Jesus? How can the son of the Most High God be the most High God Himself?

@AlexBalilo - the source of truth is NOT what appears logical to you, but the Bible.

If you choose to present the source of truth as not logical is up to you. God would not invite humans to reason if He is not a God of reason.

@AlexBalilo - I am not suggesting the Bible is illogical - far from it - it is perfectly logical to me - our reasoning must be subject to the Bible and NOT making the Bible subject to human reason.

So asking "how can the Son of the Most High God be the Most Hgh God Himself is making the bible subject to human reason? If the bible is perfectly logical to you, How can the Son of the Most High God be the Most High God Himself?

@AlexBalilo - that was the ancient idea of the succession of kings - when the reigning king wanted to anoint his successor, he sat him on the same throne and became his equal.  Thus, the son the king became the king.  That is perfectly logical - God's son is still God.  Again, your logic is not the standard of truth - the Bible is.

I see that you would like to present your logic as the standard of truth, even though though it's illogical. So you say that the Jewish followers of Jesus day view him as the the Most High God, even though Jesus himself said that his father is greater than him, Your reasoning reveals a circularity of thought based on a postulation that Jesus is YHWH. These is no verse supporting that Jesus is YHWH of the OT, None of the prophets of the OT identified Jesus as YHWH, your idea of Jesus as YHWH of the OT is from a later period,  there is proof of it. Is Jesus really  the most High God?

@AlexBalilo - that is simply untrue - I am setting forth what the Bible says - that Jehovah of the OT is Jesus in the NT as evidenced by the data in my answer.  It is true that Jesus says that the Father is greater that He but ONLY during His incarnation.  You are welcome to refute my data and analysis BUT if you do use all the Bible data, not just the verses you want.

Is it true that Jesus said that "the Father is greater than he but ONLY during his incarnation" or did you add your idea of "but ONLY during His incarnation?

@AlexBalilo - we have been here countless time before with exactly the same issues over and over again.  Please desist.

I though you said I am welcome to refute your data and analysis, now you want me to desist. You didn't answer 1. how can Jesus be the son of the most high God and be the most high God himself,, 2. Did Jesus really say that "the Father is greater than he but ONLY during his incarnation? You say they recognize Jesus as YHWH, yet the bible shows that no apostle patriarch, prophet or even Jesus himself taught that he is YHWH. Did the Jewish followers of Jesus really believe that their fellow Jew from Galilee is YHWH? Or is that idea from a later period? Is Jesus the most high or not?

@Dottard, When the skeptical Thomas concluded, "My Lord and my God," in John 20:28, Jesus could have corrected Thomas if Thomas had misrepresented who Jesus was. Jesus could have provided any number of explanations corresponding to a great variety of mischaracterizations put forward through the centuries. But instead, Jesus replied, “Have you believed because you have seen me? Blessed are those who have not seen and yet have believed.” Therefore, we know that Thomas had it right--my Lord and my God!

@AlexBalilo - I am happy for you to refute my evidence and conclusion but you never do - you simply state your conclusion repeatedly.  You never deal with any of the evidence presented including Phil 2:5-11 about Jesus' voluntary humiliation during which He had to say that the Father was greater that He was.

@Dottard. If Jesus is 100% God, there should be no instance where he is not equal with God. Does Jesus' "voluntary humiliation" mean he is not 100% God? "during which He had to say that the Father was greater that He was"?

@AlexBalilo - During Jesus' incarnation and voluntary humiliation, He remained fully God but put aside His divine powers and became subject to the Father.  After the resurrection (Phil 2:9-11) he was re-exalted back to His full glory (John 17:4, 5)

@Dottard. John 17:4 says nothing about Jesus being God.

@AlexBalilo - I did not claim that it did.  All, I said was that after the resurrection, Jesus would be restored to His full glory with the father as per John 17:4, 5 (note V5).

@Dottard. How does this "glory" support your Jesus is YHWH idea?

@AlexBalilo - I was not arguing that - I was arguing that Jesus voluntarily put aside his prerogatives of deity during the incarnation which were restored after the resurrection.

I want to address the following statement of yours. "These (should read there) is no verse supporting that Jesus is YHWH of the OT, None of the prophets of the OT identified Jesus as YHWH,"
Isaiah 7:14, "Therefore the Lord Himself will give you a sign; Behold, a virgin will be with child and bear a son, and she will call His name Immanuel." Matthew 1:23, "Behold, the virgin shall be with child, and shall bear a Son, And shall call His name Immanuel, which translated means, "God with us."
Malachi 3:1, "Behold, I am going to send My messenger, and he will clear the way before Me, (Who's the Me that's talking Alex?) And the Lord, whom you seek, will suddenly come to His temple; and the messenger of the covenant, in whom you delight, behold, He is coming, says the Lord of hosts."
The Bible says that Jesus Christ is the true temple at John 2:19, "Destroy this temple, and in three days I will raise it up." Jesus also said to the Jews at Joh 5:46-47, "For if you believed Moses, you would believe Me. Vs47, But if you do not believe his writings, how will you believe My words?" And Luke 24:27, "And beginning with Moses and with all the prophets, He explained to them the things concerning Himself in all the Scriptures.
So, where did Moses speak of Jesus Christ in the Scriptures? Let's start with Exodus chapter 3. Vs1, "Moses was pasturing the flock in the wilderness and came to Horeb, the mountain of God." Vs2, "And the angel of the Lord appeared to him in a blazing fire from the midst of a bush; and he looked, and behold, the bush was burning with fire, yet the bush was not consumed."
Vs3, So Moses said, I must turn aside now, and see this marvelous sight, why the bush is not burned up." Vs4, When THE LORD saw that he turned aside to look; GOD CALLED TO HIM FROM THE MIDST OF THE BUSH, and said Moses, Moses. And he said, "Here I am."
Vs5, "Then He/God said, Do not come near here; remove your sandals from your feet, for the place on which you are standing is holy ground." Vs6, He/God said also, "I am the God of your father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob." Then Moses hid his face, for he was afraid to LOOK AT GOD."
Now, since Jesus Christ Himself stated at John 5:37, "And the Father Himself, who sent Me, has testified of Me. You have neither heard His voice at any time, nor seen His form." So, who's voice did Moses hear according to Exodus 3;4? And John 6:46, "Not that any man has seen the Father, except the One who is from God; He has seen the Father." Since many say Jesus is a created man, how was He able to see God the Father?
By using "deductive" reasoning it must be that the angel of the Lord is the preincarnate Jesus Christ. It should also be noted that Stephen at Acts 7 mentions the angel of the Lord in his "dressing down" of the Jews. Vs38, "This is the one who was in the congregation in the wilderness together with the angel who was speaking to him/Moses on Mount Sinai,(Notice that Stephen identifies the angel of the Lord as God speaking to Moses on Mount Sinai) and who was with the fathers; and he received living oracles to pass on to you."
To prove the identity of the angel of the Lord the following is what I wrote about 2 years ago. It is rather lengthy but I covered all my bases in this presentation.
Yes, it is clear as crystal that the angel of the Lord/Jesus Christ is identified as the Lord God in His pre-existence before His incarnation in the New Testament. In fact, by you quoting Genesis 22;15-16 you have given the best proof of all in the entire Bible IMO. I will be happy to explain why.
Genesis 22:15-17, "Then the angel of the Lord called to Abraham a second time from heaven." (At Genesis 22:11 was the first time the angel of the Lord called from heaven.) vs16, and said, "By Myself I have sworn, declares the Lord because you have done this thing, and not withheld your son, your only son, vs17, indeed I will greatly bless you and I will greatly multiply your seed as he stars of the heavens, and the sand which is on the seashore; and you seed shall possess the gate of his enemies."
Please notice from vs16 the words "and said." What did the angel of the Lord say? "By Myself I have sworn, declares the Lord etc." The following is from the book of Hebrews in the NT at Hebrews 6:13-16.
"For WHEN GOD made the promise to Abraham, since He could swear by no one greater, HE SWORE BY HIMSELF, vs14, saying, I will surely bless you, and I will surely multiply you." Vs15, And thus, having patiently waited, he obtained the promise. Vs16, For men swear by one greater than themselves, and with them/men an oath given as confirmation is an end of every dispute."
Now, it is true that that, "The Law of Agency deals with the status of a person (known as the agent) acting by direction of another (the principal), and thereby legally binding the principal in his connection with a third person.The information I just gave is from the Jewish Law of Agnecy/Shaliach found in the Jewish Encyclopedia, page 232.
However, from the Jewish Virtual Library the law of agency most if not all of the time deals with, "laws of mamonot (commercial law), or (heave offering), sacrifices, divorce, and betrothal etc. According to the Tosefta (Kid, 4:1), Bet Shammai and Bet Hillel agreed that a person appointed to carry out a specific mandate is disqualified from acting as a witness in a case involving such mandate. The agent/Shaliach is not regarded as the principal as himself since the agent is disqualified from testifying as a witness.
Swear means to state under oath. Swearing an oath is a matter of one's own conscience, therefore Angels cannot swear oaths on behalf of God Himself and Jesus Christ is not an angel but rather the "messenger of the Lord." Angels cannot multiply descendants but the angel of the Lord multiplied Hagars descendants at Genesis 16:10.
The angel of the Lord appeared in the burning bush at Exodus 3:2-6 and claimed to be God at vs6. He appeared to Joshua at Joshua 5:13-15 and said at Joshua 6:2, "And the Lord said to Joshua I have given you Jerico. At Judges 2:1, the3 angel of the Lord brought you up out of Egypt and led you into the land I HAVE SWORN to your fathers, and said I will never break My covenant."
To be sure, I could give many more references where the angel of the Lord intervened on behalf of Isarael and its people as a mediator. Lastly, there is Malachi 3:1, "Behold, I am going to send My messenger, and he will clear the way before Me, And the LORD whom you seek will suddenly come to His temple; and the messenger of the covenant, in whom you delight, behold, He is coming, says the Lord of hosts." Who do you think this is? Also read Luke 1:68-79. As a side note, the angel of the Lord never appears in the New Testament as the angel of the Lord, although He is mentioned by Stephen at Acts 7.
The Hebrew word for angel is "malak." It means "Messenger, Sent One, Angel. The context determines how it is used. At Malachi 3:1, God says, I am going to send My angel/messenger, and he will clear the way before Me" This is referring to John the Baptist and John is not an angel. Continuing on with the verse, "And the Lord whom you seek, will suddenly come to His temple;" This is the Lord Jesus Christ.
Continuing on. and the malak/angel/messenger of the covenant, in whom you delight, behold, He is coming, says the Lord of hosts." This is referring to "THE" angel of the Lord, the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ who is not an angel but the "messenger" of the Lord in the OT. As a side note, the prophet Malachi, (a human being) well his name is from the word "malak/messenger." Human prophets are messengers.
Now, the poster of this thread (SLM) immediately quoted Genesis 22:15-16 wanting to know, the identity of the angel of the Lord. When I address this issue, I use or post Genesis 22:15-16 last and then I quote Hebrews 6:13-17 which backs up the identity of the angel of the Lord as God. Why? Because it is God who swore the oath to Abraham and at Genesis it's the angel of the Lord who swore the oath, which means that the angel of the Lord is not an actual angel because it is proven from these text angels can't swear oaths on behalf of God. That's also why the text says God swore the oath, "By Myself."
Now, Anne ask a legitimate question from Genesis 22:15-16, but it was a question in isolation as it relates to the angel of the Lord. Personally, I always start this issue with Genesis 16:7. Why? Because this is the first mention of the angel of the Lord as the angel of the Lord.
He says to Hagar at Genesis 16:8, "Where have you come from and where are you going? At vs9, TAOL says, "Return to Sarai. Vs, TAOL says, "moreover, I will greatly multiply your descendants so that they shall be too many to count." At vs11, he says, "Behold, you are with child and describes the child as a wild donkey of a man. In today's context Ishmael is the progenitor of the Arabs.
At vs13 Hagar says, "Then she called the name of the Lord who spoke to her, "Thou are a God who sees; for she said, "Have I even remained alive here after seeing Him." Now watch this? Genesis 17:1-5, "Now when Abraham was ninety-nine years old, the Lord appeared to Abraham and said to him. (this was a physical appearance).
I am God Almighty; Walk before Me, and be blameless. Vs2, And I will establish My covenant between Me and you, And I will multiply you exceedingly. Vs3, "And Abraham fell on his face and God talked with him, saying, Vs4, "As for Me, behold My covenant is with you, And you shall the father of a multitude of nations. Vs5, No longer shall you name be called Abram, But your name shall be Abraham; For I will make you the Father of a multitude of nations."
So here's the question? Is the being that multiplied Hagar's descendants the same being who multiplied Abraham's descendants? The reason I know this was a physical appearance of God is from Genesis 17:22, "And when He finished talking with him/Abraham, God went up from Abraham."
The angel of the Lord also appeared (physically) again to Abraham at Genesis 18 along with two actual angels. All through Genesis 18 God and Abraham have an interesting conversation which you can read for yourselves. At Genesis 18:33, (the last verse) says, "And as soon as He had finished speaking to Abraham the Lord departed; and Abraham returned to his place. What about the two angels? Genesis 19:1, "Now the two angels came to Sodom in the evening etc."
So now we know who the angel of the Lord is and what he did at Genesis 22:15-18. And as stated earlier, the angel of the Lord makes numerous appearances in the OT.

The "Me" that You ask about is YHWH. note that there are 2 messengers mentioned in Malachi 3:1, the first one mentioned as My messenger was later identified as John the Baptist, the messenger of the covenant is Jesus. who never referred to the Jerusalem Temple as his temple, John 2:16. So reading Malachi 3:1, So, who will come to whose temple, I Cor, 6:19-20 1 Cor. 3:16-17 Luke 2:49? Jesus is the messenger of the covenant who came in his Father's name as an apostle and messenger. Heb. 3:1

Right, the "Me" is YHWH. And right again, the first messenger is JTB. Indeed, the second messenger is Jesus. Now, what person is JTB introducing us to at John 1:23, "He said, I am a voice of one crying in the wilderness, Make straight the way of the Lord, as Isaiah the prophet said." At Mark 1:9 JTB identifies Jesus as the Lord. This is confirmed at Mark 1:11 by Jesus' Father, "and a voice came out of the heavens; Thou art My beloved Son, in Thee I am well-pleased." What does you in is Isaiah 40:3, "Clear the way for the Lord in the wilderness; Make smooth in the desert a highway for our God."

Jesus and JTB are messengers. A messenger is not equal to or greater than the one that sent him. God is not the messenger of the covenant.

The OP asks about the views of "people of the Bible," "John's contemporaries" and "followers of Jesus." The question cannot be definitely answered on the basis of biblical hermeneutics because we don't know for certain how earliest Christians thought about scripture. Here are some observations.

The Book of Revelation was one of the last books to be accepted into the canon. John's contemporaries may not have read it at all, let alone given it credence as scripture. So the fact that John called Jesus Lord of Lords etc. probably would not influence them, especially those who were non-Jews and thus had little familiarity with the Hebrew Bible.

The issue of Christ's divinity became a major issue in later centuries, but how John's contemporaries viewed this issue is unknown. From the writings of the church fathers, we learn that the Ebionites and possibly other Jewish-Christian groups denied Christ's divinity. But this term was first used by Irenaeus in the late second century. Jewish Christianity was more prevalent before the destruction of Jerusalem in 70 c.e., so we may presume that among John's contemporaries, the tendency toward a low christology was more prevalent than in Irenaeus' day.


Conclusion: the answer depends largely on which of John's contemporaries we are thinking of. In any case the question deals with the theological opinions of various Christian-based groups or individual hearers of the word, who may not have yet been thinking of either John's writing or any other Christian works as "scripture."

So where do we get answers about questions from the bible with out going beyond what is written. Should we assume an idea as correct without comparing it with what was already established as true and correct earlier. If a verse say Jesus is Lord of lords, Rev.and in Deuteronomy. we find YHWH    is Lord of lords, are we really stating the truth if we say Jesus is YHWH without explaining if he also is God of gods. Did the people of God at the time this was written also believe that Jesus is the God of gods?

@Dan Fefferman, In John 20, the skeptical Thomas responded to Jesus with the statement, "My Lord and my God." This provided Jesus with the Perfect Opportunity to correct the statement made by Thomas. So, how did Jesus answer Thomas?

+1.  This is a helpful remark, although it side-steps the matter of the frequent use of YHWH's titles in the NT; thus, at least, the NT writers believed Jesus was the Jehovah of the OT.

@Dan Fefferman. As your answer shows that "The issue of Christ's divinity became a major issue in later centuries". The idea that Jesus is YHWH is not present at the time of Jesus or any time.  There is no prophet or apostle that taught Jesus is the God of the OT. Acts 3:13. Did the Jewish followers of Jesus really believe that their fellow Jew from Galilee is YHWH? The Jesus is YHWH idea is from a later period?
